# Writing multiple lines to a .txt using a loop

Tags: c++

The assignment calls for me to use nested loops to write to a textfile. I am sure it has something do with the way I am opening and closing the ofstream object within the nested loops but I am stumped as to where/why.

```
Martha 1 1 1 1
Leela 2 2 2 2
Jorge 3 3 3 3
```

But instead I am getting

```
Martha 1 1 1 1Leela 2 2 2 2Jorge 3 3 3 3
```

My code is:

```
outFile.open("C:\\data\\agentSales.txt");

for (numRealtor; numRealtor > 0; numRealtor--) {
        std::cout << "\nEnter realtor's name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, realtorName);
        outFile << realtorName;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "\nValue for house " << i + 1 << "> ";
            std::cin >> salesInput;
            if (salesInput < 0 || salesInput > 200)
            {
                std::cout << "Error: Input must be between 0 and 200! :";
                std::cin >> salesInput;
            }
            outFile << " " << salesInput;

        }

    }
    outFile.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't adding a new line anywhere. You need to `outFile << '\n'` after the second loop

```
outFile.open("C:\\data\\agentSales.txt");

for (numRealtor; numRealtor > 0; numRealtor--) {
        std::cout << "\nEnter realtor's name: ";
        std::getline(std::cin, realtorName);
        outFile << realtorName;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            std::cout << "\nValue for house " << i + 1 << "> ";
            std::cin >> salesInput;
            if (salesInput < 0 || salesInput > 200)
            {
                std::cout << "Error: Input must be between 0 and 200! :";
                std::cin >> salesInput;
            }
            outFile << " " << salesInput;

        }
        outFile << '\n';
    }
    outFile.close();
```